# How to upload data from QGIS to a SQL Server?

Tags: qgis, sql

I'm new at QGIS. I'm wondering if there's a native way or plugin to allow me to upload a shapefile into my SQL Server directly from QGIS. So far the only solution that I could find is the Shape2SQL tool.

Comment: I have used a simple 'drag and drop' in the QGIS browser panel... but i'm getting errors about spatial_ref_sys and geometry_columns tables already existing...